# How to assign copy to clipboard button to specific text HTML & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I'm trying to create a number of buttons on my site to copy respective texts to clipboard, but all the buttons seem to be copying the last text.

I used a different `id` attribute for each text to be copied and a matching `id` attribute in the JavaScript `getElementById()` area for that text.

I'm thinking maybe I need to use unique `onclick()` functions for each of them instead of `copyClipboard()` for all of them.

P.S: I'm not a programmer, I'm more of a script kiddie.

Here is the code I used...

(Both buttons end up copying the second text. I want each button to copy its respective text.)

```
<script>

function copyClipboard() {

    var copyText = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;

   

    var input = document.createElement("input");

    input.value = copyText;

    document.body.appendChild(input);

    input.select();

    document.execCommand("copy");

    document.body.removeChild(input);

  }</script>

<button onclick="copyClipboard()">copy</button>

<p id="one">first</p>


<script>

    function copyClipboard() {

        var copyText = document.getElementById("two").innerHTML;

       

        var input = document.createElement("input");

        input.value = copyText;

        document.body.appendChild(input);

        input.select();

        document.execCommand("copy");

        document.body.removeChild(input);

      }</script>

   

    <button onclick="copyClipboard()">copy</button>

    <p id="two">second</p>
```

Comment: A page environment can only have one function with a given name. Your subsequent `copyClipboard` functions overwrite the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The following will copy text to the clipboard - hope it helps.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function copy_to_clipboard( elm_id ) {

    var text = document.getElementById( elm_id ).innerHTML;

    navigator.clipboard.writeText( text );

  }

</script>
</head>
<body>

   <button onclick="copy_to_clipboard('one')">copy first</button>

   <p id="one">first</p>

   <button onclick="copy_to_clipboard('two')">copy second</button>

   <p id="two">second</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `addEventListener` should be preferred over the old inline event handler method. You could apply event delegation by listening for click events on the document (or the closest static ancestor of all the buttons you need to handle) and checking for a button that is followed by a paragraph element. [`navigator.clipboard.writeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) can be used for simpler copying.

The snippet below is a simple implementation of this idea. Note that it does not work here because of the Stack Snippets permissions policy.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('button') && e.target.nextElementSibling?.matches('p'))
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent)
      .then(() => console.log('copied text'), error => console.error('failed to copy', error));
});
```

```html
<button>copy</button>
<p id="one">first</p>
<button>copy</button>
<p id="two">second</p>
```